# Current sense magnetics with critical/boundary conduction PFC chips

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

I was thinking of using a critical/boundary conduction PFC controller in a boost PFC.

I'm not sure how convenient it is to find an inductor with an auxiliary winding.

I can find lots of choke type inductors in the inductance and current range I need.  I do not know much about chokes.  Is it feasible to use 1 winding of a choke as my inductor, and the other as a current sense winding?

If I use a choke or inductor without an aux winding, have I removed the opportunity for designing a critical/boundary conduction PFC?

Comment: Neat topic. I looked it up: http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-03232001-044800/unrestricted/chapter1.pdf,
It looks like the aux winding is for reducing voltage stress on the bulk capacitor, and isn't integral to the critical/boundary conduction PFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the BCM controllers out there expect a voltage input from the supplemental PFC choke winding to tell it when to start the next cycle. You could somewhat reproduce this signal with a current transformer between the inductor and the boost diode. Rectify the secondary side signal and apply it to the control pin, and see what happens.

That being said, you probably should consider spinning your own magnetics for this powertrain. That way you know exactly what you're getting and won't end up paying extra for some feature or capability you don't need. The design process is fairly straightforward as well, especially if you design with distributed-gap toroidal inductor cores (just add turns!)

Comment: Is the supplemental PFC choke winding just the second winding that would be connected in parallel with the first winding for a common mode choke EMI filter application?

Comment: It doesn't need to be the same gauge (it's not carrying heavy current), it's phased opposite to the power winding (the windings on a CM filter inductor are in phase with each other) and it's generally fewer turns than the other winding (it doesn't need to power a big load). The exact number of turns in the aux winding will depend on your specific BCM controller. An example from the [FAN7390](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-8035.pdf) app note has 34 turns for the power winding and 4 turns for the ZCD aux winding.

Answer (score 2):

A CCM PFC system senses inductor zero current - usually with an auxiliary winding on the main inductor.

While you do not have to use a winding to sense the inductor current, this is how it is usually done, as it is usually cheaper and easier than most alternatives.

At first glance, it seems a current sense of any sort in the main inductor leg would work, but a small voice in the back of my brain suggests that current and magnetic field may not wish to work as closely in step as desired. The Hall sensor suggested below sounds closest to a secondary winding.

**BUT** you can possibly use resistive current sense - as seen here on the low side in [Fairchild App Note 42047 - Power Factor Correction Basics](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an-42047.pdf)  in fig 13. Note that for CCM the sense would need to be moved to the high side adjacent to the inductor, making the sense amplifier design "interesting". This app note appears to be of 2004 vintage and they do not seem to know about CCM as of that date.

A non coupled series current transformer *may* work.

I have not seen it done, but you should be able to use a Hall sensor to measure inductor field.  I'd expect there would be a good chance that this would be relatively straight forward and effective method.

---

A few hours of reading here :-}
[Application Notes for  Power Factor Controllers](https://www.onsemi.com/design/resources/design-resources/appnotes?category=981)

- a look at how they do the current sense in each case may be useful.

This looks like an excellent introduction.
[Fairchild AN6102 - design of PFC with FAN7528](https://web.archive.org/web/20130131202959/http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-6012.pdf) & [FAN7527](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an-4107.pdf)

[Tutorial - useful](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an-42047.pdf)

[Relevant](https://web.archive.org/web/20131215145212/http://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Eecen4517/materials/refs/inverters/VPIspectrumBCM.pdf)

---

Other:

Secondary winding pretty much has their vote

[AN-6026 Design of Power Factor Correction Circuit Using FAN7529](https://web.archive.org/web/20140719034947/http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-6026.pdf)

[AN-9738 Design Guideline on 150W Power Supply for LED Street Lighting Design Using FL7930B and FAN7621S](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an-9738.pdf)

[FAN6961: Power Factor Controller (PFC), CrCM](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/ac-dc-power-conversion/power-factor-controllers/fan6961)

[NCP1608: Critical Conduction Mode PFC Controller Utilizing a
Transconductance Error Amplifier](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP1608-D.PDF)

[Evaluation of Input Current in the Critical Mode Boost PFC Converter for Distributed Power Systems](https://web.archive.org/web/20131215145212/http://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Eecen4517/materials/refs/inverters/VPIspectrumBCM.pdf)

[App Note AN4107: Design of Power Factor Correction Using FAN7527](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an-4107.pdf)

[App Note AN4121: Design of Power Factor Correction Circuit Using FAN7527B](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an-4121.pdf)

[UCC2805x, UCC3805x Transition Mode PFC Controller](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28050.pdf)